# Getting the structure of a raw queryset in django to serialize it or to browse data

Tags: django, serialization, django-queryset

Doing:

```
datas = models.Lfsa_eisn2.objects.raw("SELECT id, AREA_CODE_ID, OCUPATION_ID, YEAR_ID, GROUP_CONCAT(`cipher` separator ',') as `cipher` from core_lfsa_eisn2 group by  AREA_CODE_ID , OCUPATION_ID,YEAR_ID" )

datas = list(datas)

print datas
...
 OC9 Elementary occupations
 S Other service activities
 2012 UK United Kingdom
 True     
 45.0,4.3,12.8,16.8,16.0,2619.3,:,60.2,57.2,247.4,344.0,208.2,5.5,42.4,455.5,87.1,233.4,24.1,168.6,180.5,362.2,:,43.9>]
...
```

Where for example `0C9(OCUPATION_ID)` is the foreign key pointing to Elementary occupations.
I'd like to do something like `datas.ocupation_id` to get OC9 or Elementary occupations.
Do you know how to get the meta data structure of the raw object?

It should be something like print `datas.meta` or `datas.field`s...I didn't get after quite time looking and trying...

I want to obtain some info like this:

```
[{'id': 1, 'OCUPATION_ID': 'Elementary occupations', 'AREA_CODE_ID': 'United Kingdom'}]
```

In resume, basically I do not understand the structure of the raw queryset object data structure to access to it and later to serialize for JSON. What are your advices?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please format some of that code. Its very hard to understand in its current form.

Comment: I'm not able to decipher the structure of the raw result. The format is what is showed after the "print datas": no showed array index, no object structure...no idea about how to format by now. I need method of datas to get the meta information or something like that...

Answer (score 1):

Well, first things first. After you did:

```
datas = list(datas)
```

datas became a `list` object (not `RawQuerySet`). Probably, you don't need this line.

This leaves us with just:

```
datas = models.Lfsa_eisn2.objects.raw("... ultraviolent SQL query ...")
```

Now datas is a proper `RawQuerySet`. Let's print its attributes. `Dir` function to the resque (it is universal law: don't know what to do with `obj`? `print dir(obj)` and you'll know everything):

```
>>> print dir(datas)
[..., 'columns', 'translations', ...]
```

A wild guess: probably `datas.columns` will give us `datas` structure.

```
>>> datas.columns
['id', 'area_code_id', ...]
```

Yep, that's what we need.

Now we can perform `getattr` ultraviolence and print all attributes:

```
>>> first = datas[0]
>>> for column in datas.columns:
>>>     print getattr(first, column)
```

And one other thing. You're doing ultraviolent stuff in your SQL query: you select `id` column but `GROUP BY` column list doesn't have `id` in it. Won't work in Postgres. Should work in sqlite and probably MySQL (I think it's not possible to write a query that won't work in MySQL).

Comment: Thank you very much, now I know how to access to the data structure. With datas.colums I have accessed to the fields: ['id', 'area_code_id', 'OCUPATION_ID', 'YEAR_ID', 'cipher']. But now, how could I access to the data corresponded to the foreign key? I mean, when I did print datas, I obtained OC9 Elementary occupations. OCUPATION_ID field has the data 0C9 (this field is a Foreign Key to the data "Elementary occupations" ) I'd like to access to "Elementary occupations". Any Idea?

Comment: SOLVED: Using dir(datas) "recursively" I got to know the internal structure of the raw object and I got the data I wanted. Thank you very much Nigel! (Yes, it was ultraviolent SQL, but works in MySQL-Django...thank you again!)